# Pointer to Class Member functions

Tags: c++, class, member-functions

I want to store class member function address, to local data structure(table)

```
typedef struct
{
     unsigned int id; 
     void (TCLASS::*proc)();
} TSTRUCT;
class TCLASS{
  public:  
     void tfunct();  
     const  TSTRUCT t1 = { 1, &tfunct};
};
```

Comment: Was there a *question* ? Or were you wondering why `TCLASS` is an unknown type in your struct as you're missing a forward declaration, or why `&tfunct` should be `&TCLASS::tfunct` in your declaration of `t1`?

Comment: Bad class names contest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you didn't write a question, assuming you are facing bunch of compiler errors.

See below :

```
class TCLASS ; //forward declaration 

 struct TSTRUCT
{
     unsigned int id; 
     void (TCLASS::*proc)( );
    // // Use the TSTRUCT constructor
    TSTRUCT(int i, void (TCLASS::*fptr)( ) ): id(i), proc(fptr) 
    {
    }

} ;

class TCLASS{
  public:  
     void tfunct(); 
    TCLASS() : t1(1, &TCLASS::tfunct ) // initialize the const member
                    //~~~~~~~~~~~^ Use &TCLASS::tfunct instead of &tfunct
    {

    }
     const  TSTRUCT t1;
};
```